# Why is Maps stuck on a purple loading screen?

Tags: windows-8, macbook-pro

I've tried opening the Maps program a dozen times. Sometimes it asks for location authorization, but it never goes past the Maps logo screen.

Specs:

- Maps
- Windows 8 Professional x64
- MacBook Pro 2009

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you're running Windows 8 on a MacBook? That seems somewhat uncommon.

Comment: What happens if you turn off the location? I'm assuming it is running into an exception when it tries to get the location information from the MacBook.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Not at all. Apple Mac OS X comes with a built-in utility for dual booting Mac and Windows: Boot Camp.

Comment: @mcandre: Oh, I wasn't aware Boot Camp was working with Windows 8 already. Happy to learn that :)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg BootCamp is *not* working with Windows 8. Hence my post about manual trackpad configuration: http://superuser.com/questions/495693/windows-8-doesnt-detect-my-macbook-pro-trackpad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maps, I pressed F1 on my MacBook Pro and randomly, Maps decides to start working. Now it never fails to load.

*post hoc ergo propter hoc*? Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the latest BootCamp drivers from Apple you never know what and update can do.Go check Apple website for latest BootCamp Drivers for Windows 8.You can also try WinClone although the download is chargeable.Link here:https://www.twocanoes.com/winclone/

Comment: Thanks. Apple doesn't release Boot Camp drivers incrementally. Boot Camp is bundled with OS X, so you only see Boot Camp updates when a new OS X comes out.