# Lost Multitouch when installing Windows8 on my Acer Aspire S3-951

Tags: windows-8

What is needed to enable it again?

I have installed the synaptic drivers from acers homepage but it did't do anything but add a useless tab to the mouse settings in control panel. (which SHOULD contain the settings for multitouch but doesnt)

Comment: I reinstalled since updating has never really worked out well for me before.

Comment: Try installing the Win7 drivers from Synaptics's [**website**](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers). The Acer site might not point to the latest.

Comment: Are you sure your system has the Synaptic hardware and not the Elantech?

Comment: I had a similar problem with my Mac. http://superuser.com/questions/495693/windows-8-doesnt-detect-my-macbook-pro-trackpad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acer updated their site [with the drivers](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers) for Win8 for those of us upgrading so you should be able to find the appropriate drivers there (note that those on Synaptics' site are outdated).

Also, as @ernie mentioned, you should probably be using Elantech's drivers (those at least were the ones working for my S3-951).

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade the drivers, then reupgrade them:

1. Open `Device Manager`.
2. Uninstall all drivers for the trackpad devices.
3. Install `Generic USB Device` drivers for the trackpad devices.
4. Test trackpad for basic functionality (move cursor + left click).
5. Use the search function to finally upgrade the trackpad devices.