# MacBook White 2010 Unibody - Upgrading from Windows 8.1 to 10 on BootCamp?

Tags: macos, windows-8, upgrade, boot-camp, windows-10-preview

I have Windows 8.1 installed (not by upgrading from 8) on my MacBook White Unibody 2010 via BootCamp. Before, I had Windows 7 installed and searching through the internet tells me that if I upgrade Mac OSX operating system I will lose everything on my Windows partition. But in order to install Windows 8.1, I had to upgrade my Mac OSX from Snow Leopard to Mavericks (Free) in which I did (thus Windows 8.1 now). By doing so I had to reinstall Windows because the old partition after upgrading the Mac OSX is practically dead.

(*All of the above just tells you that I have not ever performed a Windows "upgrade" (not the clean install) whatsoever.*)

As of recently I am eligible for a free Windows 10 upgrade (by having Windows 7/8/8.1 installed). But because I have never performed a Windows upgrade before on the BootCamp setup that I have, I have no idea if it would work or not. Windows 10 Technical Preview works (I haven't tried it myself but a few people did successfully install it) and will install as far as I know so I am quite confident the full version of Windows 10 is compatible but getting there is the problem.

My question is "**Can I do a Windows 10 upgrade when I'm on BootCamp or do I have to reinstall a new copy of Windows every time I want a new Windows OS?**"

If I don't have to reinstall a new copy then I could save about ~90GBP depending on what the Windows 10 price will be.

PS. The free Windows 10 upgrade offer is not on disc. It's downloaded and installed through Windows Update.

Comment: Are you asking if Bootcamp will support Windows 10?  When Bootcamp supports Windows 10 it will involved upgrading to the current version of OS X.  I encourage you to wait until Windows 10 is released, and I also encourage you to update your OS X installation, in order to avoid potential problems with Bootcamp.

Comment: What makes you believe updating Mac OS will lose your Windows partition? I've independently updated Mac from 10.4 all the way, over the years to 10.10. My Bootcamp has gone from XP to Win7 [& soon to be 10] without ever losing data from either.

Comment: @Ramhound That too and would upgrading Windows while on BootCamp work or do I have to reinstall from scratch if I want a new OS?

Comment: @HatsuneVocaloidMiku - While [this](http://superuser.com/questions/494384/how-hard-is-it-to-upgrade-my-boot-camp-windows-7-to-windows-8?rq=1) question is about a Windows 7 bootcamp being upgrade to Windows 8, the qustion and answer, still applies to your follow-up question.

Comment: @Tetsujin Nothing. Nothing at all. In fact I haven't tried it. But that's not the point. I just said all that so that you know I haven't ever performed a Windows upgrade whatsoever. All that's been done and dusted, Windows 8.1 installed and I'm looking forward to use the new Windows 10.

Comment: I'd wait for someone braver to try it first [it's not going to be released for a while yet anyway] but you'd need to be certain the Bootcamp Win drivers will still work, or be updated.

Comment: @Ramhound The free Windows 10 upgrade is not on disc. It's downloaded and installed through Windows 8.1. Similar to the upgrade from 8 to 8.1 so I don't know the consequences because I've never done that.

Comment: @HatsuneVocaloidMiku - If you wait you can use a disk.  Even if you don't wait, and you disregard some really helpful advice, the upgrade process is the same if you install through Windows Update or through a disk.  I guarantee you that come July 29th 2015 there will be an option to create an .ISO or use the pre-installed update.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh no I'm not going to disregard any advice. That's what I came here for in the first place. I can wait. I just want to try it out. If my laptop can't handle it properly then I'm happy with my Windows 8.1 fast performances. :) Thanks for helping~

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully upgraded to Windows 10 on the 2015 Retina MacBook Pro, and have been using it for some time. There have been a few issues, but mostly due to the unfinished status of the software. The Windows 8 drivers work with Windows 10 on this machine, but YMMV.

Comment: I don't mean the Technical Preview version although I don't know any real difference installation wise...did you use ISO or Upgrade through Windows 8?

Comment: @HatsuneVocaloidMiku I used the ISO.

Comment: Exactly. What I meant on the other hand was "upgrading" say, from Windows 7 to Windows 8 using Windows 8 "upgrade" and not a clean install. In this case Windows 10 will be downloaded and installed as if it's a Windows update, thus not using a disk at all (not even an upgrade disk). My question is that can it be done because I have Windows installed via BootCamp. Apple FAQ says I can "upgrade" from 7 to 8, but since 10 is not out yet, I'll just have to wait and see. By the way, Apple no longer support my model for Windows 8 and above. They stopped at Windows 7. lol. Thanks for the reply. =w=b